# How can i collect data from a table column and import that data to a div?

Tags: php, javascript

so basically i would like to collect data from a numeric column on my site, but from taking that data i would like to import it to a div.
the div will be a money counter that will continue adding on data collected from the table itself, i DO NOT want the counter to reset after every new data is entered in the table.
i would just like the data to keep adding up to a unlimited number.

example of the codes i have collected so far:

```
<script>

var 
table = document.getElementById('tableID'),

cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for 

(var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){

cells[i].onclick = function(){

console.log(this.innerHTML);


console.log(parseInt(this.innerHTML),10);

}
} </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this jQuery :

```
$('.myClassAbleToAddOnCounter').bind('click', function(){
  var currentCount = parseInt($('#myCounterTotal').html());
  var countToAdd = parseInt($(this).html());

  $('#myCounterTotal').html( currentCount + countToAdd );
});
```

Comment: thanks,
But it still doesnt want to function with the counter on my seperate div,
also the counter resets once new data is enter in the table any ideas?
all the help is appretiated.

Comment: hum... what you want is when the user click on a price (for example), this price will be added to the total ?

Comment: something similar to that,
basically a automacted action, example.

the data will be collect from the numeric column of a table within my site,
from there, the data will ADD on to the counter which it currently on the setting number and hopefully will not reset the counter exceding to a unlimited number,
the page will refresh after new updates are added speicifly into the numeric columns of the table. (i already know this coding)
Thank you for advice.

Comment: GOOD WORK,
Thank you words can not explain how grateful i am all i need to do now i hook up the link between the functions from the data on the table to the counter itself hehe :)